# Html append the div into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm in doubt with my HTML design. I have a `<div> ... </div>` section at a fixed position. I wish to reuse that `<div></div>` anywhere inside of the `body` tag.

I tried it using jQuery and JavaScript with the method of `innerhtml('...')`, `after('...')`, `append('...')`. It works, but I don't want to explain the 100 of lines with quotes, and one more thing. I wish to include that `<div></div>` more than one time.

Sample code format.

```
<html>
<head>
....
</head>

<body>
...
   <div id='includes_div'>       <!-- It hides on form load -->
      ...
      ...     <!-- having 100 of lines -->
   </div>

   <div id='div1'>
       <!-- want to include here -->
      ...
   </div>


   <div id='div2'>
       <!-- want to include here -->
      ...
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible with jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"I wish to **call** that `<div></div>`"* and *"I don't want to **explain** the 100 of lines with quotes"*. One cannot "call" a DOM element. You also wrote *"It works"*... what exactly does work and what are still having problems with?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [templating](http://mustache.github.com/)

Comment: I hope my `sample code` explain it clearly.

Comment: Do you want to put each line from `#includes_div` to separate div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should work:

```
var cont = $('#includes_div').html();
$('#div1').append(cont);
$('#div2').append(cont);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a quite a few ways to do this, below are just two that I see commonly employed.

The first is using the jQuery 'clone()' method:

```
var toClone = $('#includes_div');
var cloneContainers = $('#div1, #div2');

cloneContainers.each(function() {
    var clonedDiv = toClone.clone();
    clonedDiv.attr('id', '');
    this.append(clonedDiv);   
});
```

This will give you an exact clone of the original div and put it in each container. As it is an exact clone you need to prevent id conflicts.

Another way is to just use the content of the first div, rather than the whole of it.

```
var content = $('#includes_div').html();
var containers = $('#div1, #div2');

containers.each(function() {
    this.append(content);   
});
```

Obviously the code above is written to help break down the process, it's possible to write them both in a more compact form.